# GREP to find set of words that contain an e and an y with exactly two letters between them

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find set of words that contain an e and an y with exactly two letters between them. And i got this,

```
e..y
```

It works, but i wanna know if there is another way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: More efficiently than what? It's not clear from the question what language or tool you use to find the words.

Comment: that'll work, but the `.` could be anything not just letters. if you want to target ASCII letters, you could use this: `e\w{2}y`

Comment: `e..y` doesn't exactly mean `e and an y with exactly two letters between them`.. it would also match `e1;y` for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` matches any character, to be more specific, use a character class `[a-z]` with a quantifier `{2}`, i.e.:

```
/e[a-z]{2}y/
```

---

[image]

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T85TW1/1)

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation

Comment: Notice that `[a-z]` is [sensitive to your locale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227070/why-does-a-z-match-lowercase-letters-in-bash) and might include other characters than the 26 lowercase latin letters. For a portable, safe alternative, you can use `[[:lower:]]`.